# My SQL SELECT statement is not picking up any records when dates are the same

Tags: sql

I have an SQL Select statement (using C#) that will not pickup any records when the "from" and "to" dates are the same but works for any other dates.

For example, I have two text boxes "From Date:" and "To Date:" and when I put both dates the same (i.e. 03/21/2013) it doesn't return anything even though records do exist.

Here is my code:

```
DateTime fromDt = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text);
DateTime toDt   = Convert.ToDateTime(txtToDate.Text);
string tp       = TpId.SelectedItem.Text.Trim();
```

```
string sql  = "SELECT * FROM EDI10000 WHERE Tp_Id = '" + tp + "' and Rec_Date >= '" +  fromDt + "' and Rec_Date <= '" + toDt + "'";
```

Can anyone see what could be causing this?

thank you

**UPDATE:**

Ok I got it working thank you guys for heading me in the right direction.

I ended up adding ".ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") to my two variables "fromDt" and "toDt" and I changed my "Rec_Date" field to read "CONVERT(varchar(10), Rec_Date, 110)".

That stripped the time off all the dates.

Thank you all.

Comment: make sure the dates are converted into a unix timestamp before comparing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably going wrong in the string to DateTime conversions as the sql is comparing datetime fields to the nearest millisecond. Assuming you are intrested in comparing dates only and not intrested in the time part you could change your query to:

```
string sql  = "SELECT * FROM EDI10000 WHERE Tp_Id = '" + tp + "' and Rec_Date >= '" + fromDt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' and Rec_Date <= '" + toDt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
```

Comment: No that didn't work either. And I also changed the Rec_Date to: CONVERT(varchar(10),Rec_Date, 101)  with no luck.

Comment: Ok figured it out. I changed the format in my .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") to ("MM-dd-yyyy") so I also had to change the format in my Convert function to CONVERT(varchar(10), Rec_Date, 110) instead of the "101" format.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is if `Rec_Date` is a timestamp (datetime) field that has time and date included.  If the comparison date is simply the date (basically treated as midnight), then the comparison would fail for all values that were not exactly midnight.

For example, if `Rec_Date = 2013-03-21 15:00:00` and the start and end comparison dates were `2013-03-21`, then it would not be included because the `toDt` value would not be considered greater or equal to that value.

```
2013-03-21 15:00:00  >=  2013-03-21  ==>  TRUE
2013-03-21 15:00:00  <=  2013-03-21  ==>  FALSE
```

Comment: I tried stipping off the time also and that still didn't work.

Comment: How did you strip off the time?  You might also update the post with sample data to show an example of what is failing.

Comment: Ok I will thank you. I changed my fromDt and toDt variables to "fromDt.ToString(MM-dd-yyyy")" and the same to "toDt" and added the CONVERT(varchar(10), Rec_Date, 110) to my "Rec_Date" field.